# Coord_polar ggplot creates empty zones

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I want to draw a histogram in polar coordinates. So, I generate a random set of points.

`set.seed(123);x<-data.frame(x=rnorm(1000)+(runif(1000)-0.5)*5)`

I plot it as a histogram.

`ggplot(x,aes(x))+geom_histogram()`
obtaining the plot
[image]

But when I try to use `coord_polar`, and then the following code

`ggplot(x,aes(x))+geom_histogram()+coord_polar()+theme_void()`

I obtain the figure shown hereafter with some blank zones between bars.

[image]

How can I avoid such an effect?

I can't find suggestions for solving this issue. I expect that `coord_polar` does not create such lines, and I suppose it is a matter of numerical approximation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things at play here:

1. Raster-vs-vector graphics. The displays used in R and RStudio are raster (pixel) based, which means they can show artifacts where (e.g.) anti-aliasing is intended to mitigate them. These artifacts change on seemingly arbitrary things such as window size, zoom level, etc.

   The mitigation for this is to save and view in a vector-based format such as SVG or PDF. Using your code and then `ggsave("quux.pdf")`, I get

   [image: polar plot in pdf]
2. The gray lightened lines you see in the plot above are "intentional" based on the default action of `color=` (often paired with `fill=`). If you specify both as the same color, you'll get a smoother image.

   ```r
   ggplot(x,aes(x))+geom_histogram(color="gray30", fill="gray30")+coord_polar()+theme_void()
   ```

   [image: polar plot with no visual artifacts]

   With that PDF, I zoomed in rather closely and still see no artifacts.

Comment: Thank a lot for the the suggestions. We should wait for a viewer that will use vector instead of raster graphic display in R! :-)

Comment: I like it ... but I won't hold my breath. (Seriously, though, if you use `plotly` it is always vector-based. Alternatively, I've seen a couple of users who always plot to a PDF instead of to the pane: they always plot to the same PDF file, and have it open in a viewer, so it's always refreshed and always vector. The hard part is telling R to always use it by default instead of having to call `ggsave` each time or wrap base graphics calls in `pdf(.)`/`dev.off()`.)